# Is there any possibility for document paragraph-level tagging and filtering, e.g. by VBA or C#?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, tags, paragraph

The MS Word document has the ability to mark **tags** at the **file level**, which can be used from Windows Explorer to make it easier to search for files by document’s tags.

Is there a similar feature in MS Word for **tagging** information at the document **paragraph level**?

This would be practically useful for a quick point search of all the necessary information in a large document. With the ability to filter out all of the rest of the document's information.

Assume that MS Word allows you to tag with different tags any document's paragraphs.

Suppose, for example, that we have a document containing a textbook on mathematics for convenience.

Suppose that we can mark each paragraph of the document with the any of following tags:

- of a some concept
- definition of a some concept
- explanation of a some concept
- an example of the use of some concept.

Using a specific concept's tag, definition tag, and explanation tag to filter information, we can get a version of the original document containing only the definition and explanation paragraphs of our chosen concept. And there will be no other information.

Which can significantly increase convenience, speed, and quality of analysis of the required information.

**Is it possible to add the above functionality by using VBA macros or C#?**

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @macropod, But solving this problem will significantly help in faster, deeper, and wider assimilation of any knowledge, including those related to programming.

Comment: Regardless, the subject is off-topic here.

Comment: @macropod, Adding the above functionality to Microsoft Word will turn it into a real Knowledge Management System